# ¿Problema controlando visibilidad de botones con sentencia condicional IF - ELSE?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego, al oprimir un botón en el juego, necesitaba un delay, buscando en la red encontré, que el delay se puede hacer con un Handler, implemente el Handler y el delay funciona muy bien.

El problema que tengo, es que antes de poner el Handler, las condiciones (if - else) funcionaban bien, pero ahora que puse el Handler, las condiciones if - else, no las evalúa, pasa derecho.

¿Los botones y las variables se deben declarar de otra forma?

Gracias por sus sugerencias.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button boton_01, boton_02, boton_03;

String boton_numero = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    boton_01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    boton_02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    boton_02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

}


public void boton1(View view) {

   //En este punto la variable boton_numero puede tener un valor de 1,2 o 3.
   Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {

       // Lo que he observado es que no evalua las sentencias if-else

       if (boton_numero.equals("1")) {
    
             boton_01.setVisibility(boton_01.INVISIBLE);
 
       } else { if (boton_numero.equals("2")) {

             boton_02.setVisibility(boton_02.INVISIBLE);

       } else { if (boton_numero.equals("3")) {

             boton_03.setVisibility(boton_03.INVISIBLE);

       }


       }
   
   }, 2000);

}

}
```

Comment: Te está faltando asignar el evento que escucha los clicks, [revisa este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17960992/5587982). Y, si quieres asignar el mismo evento a varios botones, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25905313/5587982)

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia @A. Cedano. La prueba la estoy haciendo con un solo botón, lo que he notado es que antes de entrar en el Handler, el valor de la variable es visible, pero dentro del Handler el valor de la variable no es visible o leído por la condición if-else. ¿Debo definir la variable de otra forma?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no es visible? Quizá debas definir la variable como miembro de la clase si quieres alcanzarla desde diferentes métodos de la misma.

Comment: Me explico, como no sabia porque no funconaban los condicionantes if-else, coloque un texTview y una instruccion texTview.setText(boton_numero) antes del Handler y otra instruccion texTview.setText(boton_numero) despues de la instruccion **public void run()**, para ver que pasaba con el valor de la variable boton_numero. Cuando ejecuto la app, antes de pasar por el Handler el valor de la variable aparece en el textView, pero cuando esta dentro del Handler ya no aparece en el textview. Por eso pienso que el valor de la variable boton_numero no es visible en el momento de evaluar los if_else.

Comment: Pero ¿eso lo hacías para depurar el código o porque los TextView realmente debían tomar esos valores (sería extraño lo segundo hablando de un código que se ejecutará por un tiempo limitado)? Para fines de depuración lo que deberías usar es [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es-419).

Comment: Por lo poquito que conozco y medio entiendo, creo que como el Handler es un hilo aparte al hilo principal, no lee el valor de la variable, pienso que la varibale se debe definir o declarar de otra forma en el hilo principal, para que sea accesible en el hilo nuevo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que depures usando Logcat, para que estés segura de lo que ocurre. Por otra parte, el planteamiento es algo confuso y eso dificulta poder ayudarte con más propiedad. Sobre la escucha de los clicks, seguimos sin ver nada en la pregunta, ¿cómo lo estás implementando?

Answer (score 0):

1. Para usar el método `onClick()`, debes implementar la interfaz `View.OnClickListener`

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

2. Para definir la visibilidad de un botón no uses la propiedad del botón, usa la constante `View.INVISIBLE`, por ejemplo:

   ```
   //boton_01.setVisibility(boton_01.INVISIBLE);
     boton_01.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   ```
3. Para que entre en alguna opción de tu if-else, esta variable debe tener un valor:

   String boton_numero = "1";

por lo tanto, realiza el siguiente cambio en tu código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button boton_01, boton_02, boton_03;

String boton_numero = "1";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    boton_01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    boton_02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    boton_02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    //Asigna listener
    boton_01.setOnClickListener(this);
    boton_02.setOnClickListener(this);
    boton_03.setOnClickListener(this);

}


public void onClick(View view) {

   Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {

       if (boton_numero.equals("1")) {
    
             boton_01.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 
       } else { if (boton_numero.equals("2")) {

             boton_02.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

       } else { if (boton_numero.equals("3")) {

             boton_03.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

       }


       }
   
   }, 2000);

}

}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia @Jorgesys. Si, en el ejemlo la varible la defini sin valor, pero cuando llega al boton lleva un valor que puede ser 1,2,3,...9. La prueba la estoy haciendo con un solo botón. He validando con un texTview y un texTview.setText(boton_numero) antes de entrar en el Handler, el valor de la variable boton_numero es visible (1,2,3,...), pero dentro del Handler el valor de la variable no es visible o leído por la condición if-else.  ¿Debo definir la variable de otra forma?

Comment: El problema es que el handler se va a ejecutar 2 segundos después, necesitas que se ejecute 2 segundos después? me parece que es innecesaria su definición.

Comment: De pronto no me he hecho entender, lo que necesito, es que despues de tocar el boton, éste siga visible 2 segundos antes de hacerse invisible.